# Incorrect cardview element show in some phone

Tags: android, layout, android-cardview

I create a RecyclerView layout thats show some details of vehicle but in some phone not correct show and ignore some view pupulate.
this is my RecyclerView  like below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".Main">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtpel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:text="news"></TextView>
<View
    android:id="@+id/viewdevi"
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="4dp"
    android:background="#EA4D8A"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtpel"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/cardList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:layout_below="@+id/viewdevi"
    android:paddingBottom="30dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    ></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

and a cardview layout like below:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/card_view_newpelak"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
android:gravity="right"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="bottom|right">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/pellog"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:background="#c0bfbc"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pellogimg"
        android:src="@drawable/omomicar"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relimghead"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/pellog"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pelakasli"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/alef"
        />
    </RelativeLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/reltxt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/pellog"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relimghead"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtpeldet"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:text="TEXT"
            android:textColor="#ea1e63"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

but when that show correct in some device but not correct device like Honor 6x and some of Samsung phones show empty inside.
this picture show correct view :

[image]

and this picture show bad view:

[image]

anyone can help to fix this problem??

and this is my populated function:

```
private List<PLDataModel> createList() {
    ArrayList<Integer> carMiniLogo = new ArrayList<>();
        carMiniLogo.add(R.drawable.polit1);
        carMiniLogo.add(R.drawable.polit2);
        carMiniLogo.add(R.drawable.polit3);
        carMiniLogo.add(R.drawable.polit4);
        carMiniLogo.add(R.drawable.polit5);
        carMiniLogo.add(R.drawable.polit6);

    ArrayList<Integer> carBigImage = new ArrayList<>();
        carBigImage.add(R.drawable.dip);
        carBigImage.add(R.drawable.dipto);
        carBigImage.add(R.drawable.dipre);
        carBigImage.add(R.drawable.dipo);
        carBigImage.add(R.drawable.dipme);
        carBigImage.add(R.drawable.dipsee);


    ArrayList<String> carDetailes = new ArrayList<>();
        carDetailes.add("Some text");
        carDetailes.add("Some text");
        carDetailes.add("Some text");
        carDetailes.add("Some text");
        carDetailes.add("Some text");
        carDetailes.add("Some text");

    List<PLDataModel> result = new ArrayList<PLDataModel>();
    for (int i=0; i < carBigImage.size() ; i++) {
        PLDataModel ci = new PLDataModel();
        ci.setCarBigImage(carBigImage.get(i));
        ci.setcarMiniLogo(carMiniLogo.get(i));
        ci.setPelakDetails(carDetailes.get(i));
        result.add(ci);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: please post the code for populating the cardView. It seems that it fails to get the data for populating views on those device. Have you tried to debug it on one of the devices that has this problem?

Comment: @Merka thanks for yr quick comment i add function.
no i not access this phone model that user reports me.

Comment: So your data is available offline and hardcoded in your code and you don't retrieve it from a server?

Comment: no they are offline